# Display Image in Drupal View

Tags: image, drupal, view

I set up a view to show the movie poster of a movie from a field that has the url (e.g. http://images.zap2it.com/movies/116670/116670_aa_t.jpg)

For the argument I've tried using Node-Nid and Content: Poster Art (the field with the url) and the Field I have Content: Image (I've tried various "Image" settings).  Yet it won't show any pic, just "Image: ".

What am i missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Drupal 6?  In Drupal 7, I know that you have to specify that the field use a relationship you've set up from a drop-down, so maybe there's something similar in Drupal 6 you've forgotten to do.  Otherwise, could you look at the resulting page's source code and specify what appears in the source after 'Image: '?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I havent done anything like this before. But I think you can do this by "rewriting" the result of the url field.

You can do this by clicking the field with the url that you will find under "FIELDS" in your view settings.
Then under "Rewrite Results" you can write something like

```
<img src="[image_url]" />
```

here, 'image_url' must be the name of the field. you can verify this in the list displayed under "Replacement Patterns"

Hope this helps. :)

Regards

Aayush Shrestha

Comment: I ended up absconding the View and just linking the image_url by loading the node.

Comment: I just wanted to add that the image_url in @aayush shrestha example should be relative to the www folder of the web server. In case the image is another location, creating a symbolic link in the www folder can be considered.